# In Eclipse, in a class's Outline view, can I list class members alphabetically?

Tags: eclipse

In the "Outline" pane, the one that lists a class' methods and members, the listing is 
in order of declaration.

Any way to change that ordering to alphabetical?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse organize methods in alphabetical order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549319/eclipse-organize-methods-in-alphabetical-order) . This came later, but the mysterious forces of the universe mandated that the other get more upvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With eclipse 3.5.0 you have a button "Sort" within your outline view. Clicking on this button will sort the methods and members.

Comment: @AaronFi: I don't know if it was like this back then, but now (Eclipse 4.5.2), the "Outline" view *remembers* the order you chose. Confusingly, there is no real configuration setting for that. **Also, editors which are already open when you change the ordering are not affected by that change**. In contrast, for any newly opened files, it will stick to the last selected setting.