# Sort members in Eclipse by visibility without alphabetic sorting

Tags: eclipse, sorting, formatting

I'm curious if there is an option to sort the diefferent types like fields, methods, etc by visibility but **not by alphabet**. I know I can sort the members by using `Source -> Cleanup`. But it keeps sorting it also alphabeticaly. I just want to sort by visibility and keep the rest of the old ordering.

**Example:**

```
public class Person {

    private Person(final Long id, final String name, final String surname) {

    }

    public Person() {
    }

    private Long id;

    private String surname;

    private String name;

    public final static String SOME_CONSTANT = "SOME_CONSTANT";

}
```

**After sorting it should look like this:**

```
public class Person {

    public final static String SOME_CONSTANT = "SOME_CONSTANT";

    private Long id;

    private String surname;

    private String name;

    public Person() {
    }

    private Person(final Long id, final String name, final String surname) {
    }


}
```

**But I get:**

```
public class Person {

    public final static String SOME_CONSTANT = "SOME_CONSTANT";

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String surname;

    public Person() {
    }

    private Person(final Long id, final String name, final String surname) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure alphabetical sort is not possible in Eclipse without a plugin.
Have you tried setting custom Source->Sort Members options (Preferences->Java->Appearance->Members Sort Order) ?

However you may find some alternatives in this post: [Eclipse organize methods in alphabetical order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549319/eclipse-organize-methods-in-alphabetical-order)

Comment: @christophe-ruossy Thats the opposite of what I want. I do not want alphabetic sorting. Just a sorting by visibility modifier.

Comment: You cannot not have them separately. It always does both.