# Automatically sort member variables alphabetically

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a class:

```
public class Alphabetical {
   private String banana;
   private String apple;
   private String donut;
   private String zebra;
   private String carrot;
}
```

I want to automatically arrange the entries from A to Z (alphabetically)

I have tried https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/10/arrange-your-code-automatically-with-intellij-idea-12/ but this does not work, nothing happens when I press the *Code > Rearrange Code* menu. I am using IntelliJ 2018.2

And if this is not doable from IntelliJ, is there a maven plugin that can do this?

Answer (score 15):

Actually it is possible in Intellij. It doesn't work because the order-by-name is not enabled by default.

Go to `Settings->Editor->Code Style->Java` then click on `Arrangement` tab:

[image]

Then edit the 17th rule (the one with `field` `private`) and select in the combobox `Order` select `order by name`
[image]

Now click Apply button and try again to rearrange fields.

Comment: Of course it is not the only place where it is applicable. For instance, ordering alpha. is also applicable for 'private static final' fields but it is not the line 17 but the line 4. The idea is to change the rules where it is desired.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to install Eclipse, load the same project and do

> select the class, Source > Sort Members

based on [Eclipse organize methods in alphabetical order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549319/eclipse-organize-methods-in-alphabetical-order)